# OSI model: Does any traffic occur without Layer 7 initiation?

Tags: networking

Of course a lot of network traffic occurs at lower layers, but does anything happen without a specific Layer 7 request?

Comment: @Dan: The only possibility I can think of is ARP/RARP

Comment: @OMG Ponies Thanks—I'll keep that in mind for next question.  This answers my question for now though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is plenty of overhead traffic used solely by the network equipment. ARP requests, routing table exchanges and such. 
Keep in mind though that OSI is just a reference model and not an actual protocol stack. What is considered an application layer in one situation (http for web requests) can act as a transport for a different protocol in other situations (e.g. SOAP).

Comment: +1 for the reminder that OSI is just a model. I should add it is a model that nowadays is far from the present reality.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.  A DNS lookup uses UDP on layer 4 directly, not involving layers 5-7 at all.  I suppose you could call DNS an "application layer" request, but there's no session or state, it's really too trivial to count as such in my opinion.

Update:

Okay, I think I see what you're asking.  How about DHCP broadcasts when a host joins a network?  Technically it's the dhcp client application doing the request, but it's not (necessarily) initiated by a user.

Also, when an IPv4 interface comes online, it will do an [ARP probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#ARP_probe) to make sure the IP address it's configured with is not already in use.

Even deeper, routers and switches will exchange [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) messages when they come online and on a regular basis, and I believe this occurs even if no endpoints are even connected, e.g., two routers connected together and to nothing else.

Comment: But a DNS lookup is initiated by a program - a web browser for instance.

Comment: A DNS lookup is certainly more ephemeral than most traffic, but it's still (usually, if not always) initiated by an application request

Answer (score 0):

Even within a single TCP session there can be lower-layer traffic that's not directly triggered by higher-layer events.  The best example of this is if TCP Keepalives are enabled, which will cause TCP traffic (transport layer) triggered by a simple timeout even if there is no application-layer activity.